# I multiplied a 2D matrix using dynamic allocation and a function. Why does the address change?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

The code was constructed using the property that `the column of A and the row of B must be the same` to find the matrix product.

It worked when I multiplied the 2D matrix without using dynamic allocation, but it didn't work after using dynamic allocation with function. So I looked up the address, and the address was different by `30`.

```
int *matrixMulti(int N, int M, int L, int *A, int *B)
{

  int *Mat = (int *)malloc(N * L * sizeof(int));

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < L; j++)
    {
      *(Mat + i * M + j) = 0;
      for (int k = 0; k < M; k++)
      {
        *(Mat + i * M + j) += A[i * M + k] * B[k * M + j];
      }
      printf("Mat[%d][%d] Mat[i][j] %d Mat address : %p \n", i, j, *(Mat + i * M + j), Mat);
      printf("\n");
    }
  }

  return Mat;
}


int main()
{
  int N, M, L;
  printf("input N M L\n      ");
  scanf("%d %d %d", &N, &M, &L);

  int *A = (int *)malloc(N * M * sizeof(int));
  int *B = (int *)malloc(L * M * sizeof(int));
  int *S = (int *)malloc(N * L * sizeof(int));

  input(N, M, A);
  Array_print(N, M, A);

  input(M, L, B);
  Array_print(M, L, B);

  S = matrixMulti(N, M, L, A, B);

  printf("\n S address %p\n", matrixMulti(N, M, L, A, B)); ////////////////////////// ---> A
  printf("\n S address %p\n", S);                          ////////////////////////// ---> A-30

  // Array_print(N, L, matrixMulti(N, M, L, A, B));

  free(A);
  free(B);
  free(S);
  return 0;
}
```

At first, when only `arrays` were passed and received, matrix multiplication was also output normally, but it became strange when changing to `pointers`.

**Output**

> S address 0x159f04120

> S address 0x159f040f0

**Expected**

> S address 0x159f04120

> S address 0x159f04120

Full code [here](https://pastebin.com/JFju3Bsj)

Comment: Simply because when you call `matrixMulti` you allocate two distinct chunks of memory

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72330113/how-to-copy-data-to-a-pointer-returned-by-malloc) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58983444/dynamically-allocating-and-copying-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a simplified version of matrixMulti

```
int *matrixMulti(int N, int M, int L, int *A, int *B)
{

  int *Mat = (int *)malloc(N * L * sizeof(int));

   ////  do stuff

  return Mat;
}
```

you see that it allocates memory and returns a pointer to it.

If you call it twice you get two different allocations at different addresses

```
S = matrixMulti(N, M, L, A, B); // call #1

printf("\n S address %p\n", matrixMulti(N, M, L, A, B));  //call #2
```

EDIT

Note here

```
 S = matrixMulti(N, M, L, A, B); // call #1
```

S now contains the value returned by matrixMulti. Ie Mat

```
int *matrixMulti(int N, int M, int L, int *A, int *B)
{

  int *Mat = (int *)malloc(N * L * sizeof(int));

   ////  do stuff

  return Mat; <<<< this is what gets loaded into S
}
```

S does not contain the address of matrixMulti

Comment: Thanks for answering the question:)
According to you, shouldn't the address of call #2 and *matrixMulti be the same? But it's different.

`printf("Mat[%d][%d] Mat[i][j] %d Mat address : %p \n", i, j, *(Mat + i * M + j), Mat);`

Comment: @Jeong-ukPark - you are confusing the return value of a function with its address. I will edit my answer